# Is it possible to have several filters in a single Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to get multiple filters on the same row that filter different tables.
So users can sort data from table 1, 2 or 3 individually as they wish.
Is it possible to do that in Google sheets?

Quick sample of my data below to better understand what I'm trying to do
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ed0aBmcCN5vUYOIw3-17A2xsFVC4eCT77_nSdToP1h4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There are several filters in Google Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected filter?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
A very basic filter (like the one above the formula bar) that would cover the 3 columns of each table. For example for the first table, users will be able to filter the product ID by ascending/descending order or discount by lower/higher % or availability yes or no.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, only one basic filter can be used in the sheet. By this, your goal cannot be directly achieved. So, for example, how about the following workaround? 1. Separate your 3 tables in a sheet to 3 sheets. 2. Filtering each sheet using each basic filter. 4. Those values from 3 filtered sheets are put to another sheet. In this case, you can use the formula. By this, I think that your goal can be indirectly achieved. But, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I thought they might be a way to workaround this. But if the only solution is to create multiple sheets, then I will go for that

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, would you consider posting an answer explaining the workaround you suggested? Thank you.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your comment. I posted it as an answer by including more information. If there are excess or deficiency points, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible with the "Filter views" accessible from the menu.

1. Select your data range.
2. Go in "Filter Views" and create a new filter view.
3. Rename the filter and adjust the range if needed.
4. All the filter views that you created can be access from the menu and will be visible by other users.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From your reply, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have 3 tables in one sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to filter and sort each table using the basic filter to each table.

#### Issue:

In the current stage, unfortunately, only one basic filter is used in one sheet. And, even when the filter view is used, although the multiple filter views can be created. But, only one filter view can be used by selecting it. And, even when the slicer is used, the slicer cannot sort the rows. And, when one slicer is set to a table as the filter, that affects another table. In these situations, I thought that your goal cannot be directly achieved.

#### Workaround:

Here, in order to indirectly achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Separate your 3 tables in a sheet to 3 sheets.
2. Filtering and sorting each sheet using each basic filter.
3. Values from 3 filtered sheets are put on another sheet.

   - In this case, I think that you can use the formula.

With this workaround, I thought that your goal can be indirectly achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a workaround.  You can do this with array style notation.  You just need separate the filters with ";" and add "{" and "}" to either end of the command.
I.e. "={filter(, conditions...); filter(, conditions...)}"